Why does Svelte update the middle component after the parent and child?
See https://svelte.dev/repl/89b164da451a45a48ad12ca8f113b13a?version=4.2.15. This a condensed example of what's going on in my application.

There are 3 components: App, which renders Layout, which renders Navigation.
There are two stores: url and username.
App has a reactive statement $: if (!$username && $url !== '/login') { url.set('/login') } (e.g. to redirect back to the login page if not logged in).
Navigation is conditionally rendered only if the URL is not /login.
Navigation throws an error if username is falsey.
Pressing the logout button does username.set(null).

stores.js:
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const username = writable();
export const url = writable('/login');

App.svelte:
<script>
    import { url, username } from './stores';
    import Layout from './Layout.svelte';

    $: {
        console.log('App update', $url, $username);
        if (!$username && $url !== '/login') {
            console.info('Redirect to login');
            url.set('/login');
        }
    }
</script>
{console.log('App render', $url, $username), ''}
<Layout />

Layout.svelte:
<script>
    import { url, username } from './stores';
    import Navigation from './Navigation.svelte';

    // Adding $username here seems to fix it?
    $: console.warn('Layout update', $url);
</script>
{(console.warn('Layout render', $url), '')}
{#if $url !== '/login'}
        <Navigation />
        <button on:click={() => {
                username.set(null);
        }}>LOGOUT</button>
{:else}
        <button on:click={() => {
                username.set('admin');
                url.set('/');
        }}>LOGIN</button>
{/if}

Navigation.svelte:
<script>
    import { url, username } from './stores';
    $: try {
        console.log('Nav update', $url, $username);
        if (!$username) {
            throw new Error('Invalid user');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('EEE', err);
        //throw err;
    }
</script>
{console.log('Nav render', $url), ''}

What should happen:

Pressing the logout button sets username to null.
App reacts to username changing and sets url to /login.
Layout reacts to url changing and unmounts Navigation.
Navigation doesn't throw an error.

What actually happens:

Pressing the logout button sets username to null.
App reacts to username changing and sets url to /login.
Navigation reacts to username changing and throws an error.
(if we catch the error and allow svelte to continue) Layout reacts to url changing and unmounts Navigation.

What I would like to understand is why this is happening. Why does svelte update the parent and the child before updating the middle component?

Passing the url down to Layout as prop doesn't seem to fix it which I find even more surprising.
Adding $username to Layout fixes it.

How can you safely use conditional rendering if it's not guaranteed that a component will be unmounted before it gets updated with potentially invalid state? What am I missing here?

Include all relevant code in the question, do not just link somewhere. Questions have to be self-contained and be answerable as is.

Updated to include the code
